# Play Local Audio File on User Select (local, no server) - HTML5 / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to allow a user to select an audio file on his computer and then use the HTML5 control to play the file.  I know using `<input type="file">` will not work as it will not then pass the file location (it will use fakepath).  Is there any way to do this in a local environment (local HTML file) without a server?  To select an audio file and play it with controls?

Comment: If that is a solution it does not seem to work.

Comment: ? `input.onchange = function(){var a = new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])); a.controls = true; document.body.appendChild(a);}` That's all you need.